# add a button in a view and to call using (ng-click) function that is called buy another button in another view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two views in a single page application in one view there is a save button that save the data entered from the two view, i want to make it more reliable and ad that button into the secon view , is posible to do that knowing that each view has its own javascript file containg the controllers and functions ...
the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="saveInfo()">Save Data</button>
```

the save function in the first view is:

```
    $scope.saveInfo = function() {
console.log("saveInfo");
$scope.loadingInstance = $modal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'modalLoading.html',
  size: "l",
});

return getChanges( $indexedDB, $q).then( function(responsesArray) {
    var jsonData = {};
    $scope.errorInstance = undefined;
    for (var i=0; i < DB_TABLES.length; i++) {
        var table = DB_TABLES[i];
        var items = responsesArray[i]
        if (items.length > 0){
            jsonData[table] = items;
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    return Services.postData($scope.selectedUser, jsonData);
})
}
```